# What are the correct arguments to create an AWS aurora postgres instance using the AWS CLI?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

The following command works when the --engine is set to `postgres`, but when I change it to `aurora-postgresql` (per the docs), I get an odd error:

```
aws rds create-db-instance \
    --db-name mydb1 \
    --db-instance-identifier mydb1 \
    --db-instance-class db.r5.large \
    --engine aurora-postgresql \
    --master-username postgres \
    --master-user-password XXXXX \
    --availability-zone us-east-1a \
    --db-subnet-group-name mydb-subnets-us-east-1 \
    --allocated-storage 100
```

Error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateDBInstance operation: 
Invalid storage type for DB engine manfred: aurora
```

What is `manfred:`?

And I've attempted all of the documented `--storage-type` values I see (`standard`, `io1` and `gp2`), and they all generate the error:

```
An error occurred (StorageTypeNotSupported) when calling the CreateDBInstance operation:\n
Invalid storage type: XXX
```

I haven't been able to find a single example of creating an aurora postgres db from the CLI.  Any advice from someone who has is appreciated.

Comment: You can't set a storage type, or a specific allocated storage size, for Aurora. Aurora scales the storage automatically, and uses its own proprietary storage type. I'm guessing the `--allocated-storage 100` might be throwing it off? Also, make sure you are using the latest version of the CLI.

Comment: I am also getting same error, so I removed --allocated-storage 100 but getting error : An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateDBInstance operation: The parameter AllocatedStorage must be provided and must not be null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove --allocated-storage, as already mentioned.

You need to add the --db-cluster-identifier parameter so that AWS knows which Aurora cluster to associate the instance with. This is also how it knows that --allocated-storage is not applicable, and any other differences in required or allowed parameters for Aurora instances as opposed to RDS ones.

If you didn't already run create-db-cluster, you have to do that first so there's a DBClusterIdentifier value to fill in for create-db-instance --db-cluster-identifier.

I never use the --availability-zone parameter. Aurora already knows the 3 availability zones that are associated with the cluster. It picks one of those automatically. No point in leaving yourself open to a potential error because the cluster used -1a, -1c, and -1e and you try to use -1b for the instance.